# Rules to allow only authorized user in firebase realtime to update or delete a node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm really struggling with the security rules for firebase realtime database for this situation:

Suppose I have a node "groups" and the keys inside groups are "$groupid". The data inside each $groupid node is

```
{
    "name": some name here,
    "owner": the UID of the person who created this node
}
```

I want any authenticated user to be able to read the data, so my .read is: "auth != null && !auth.anonymous"

But for .write, I want the following:

1. Any authenticated user can create a new $groupid node. Note that when the node is created, the "owner" field is set to auth.uid in my code
2. Only the owner can update or delete that $groupid node

My first guess at this something like this:

```
{
    "group": {
        "$groupid": {
            ".read": "auth != null && !auth.anonymous",
            ".write": "auth != null && !auth.anonymous",
            ".validate": "(!data.exists() && newData.exists()) || (auth.uid === data.child('owner').val())"
        }
    }
}
```

If I understand data and newData correctly, the .validate statement says the following:

1. if data doesn't exist and newData does, then this is a create operation so it validates.
   OR
2. if the test in 1 fails, that means this is an update or delete operation and for that we must have the auth.uid equal to the stored owner.

Did I get this right? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Looks good to me at first glance. What isn't working about it? Is there an error message? Can you share the minimal code with which you get that problem against these rules?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.